# active_model_serializers : how to get custom json through the inline render :json?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I am using active_model_serializers gem in my rails 4. It works if i use

```
def search
    category_search = Category.search_for(params[:q])
    render :json => category_search
end
```

with an output like

```
[{"id":1,"name":"life","category":"Categories","label":"Life","value":"Life","url":"/search/#/category/life"}]
```

where label, url etc are custom generated details through active_model_serializers

My action

```
def search
    category_search = Category.search_for(params[:q])
    render :json => {data:[{text: "Categories", children: category_search}]}
end
```

but this only outputs, without the label and url attributes

```
{"data":[{"text":"Categories","children":[{"id":1,"name":"life"}]}]}
```

So what can i do to achieve the result i want?
thanks.

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271597/how-to-select-serializer-for-nested-objects-with-active-model-serializers